# How to open URL by Desktop object in Java?

Tags: java, url, desktop

I have a button to open a URL in browser:

```
URI uri = new URI("http://google.com/");
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.browse(uri.toURL()); // has error
```

but i get following error in last statement:

```
The method browse(URI) in the type Desktop is not applicable for the arguments (URL)
```

thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution:
1. Remove **.toURL()**
2. use **try catch** block

```
try
{
    URI uri = new URI("http://google.com/");
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
    dt.browse(uri);
}
catch(Exception ex){}
```

Comment: Do avoid empty catch blocks like that. It's a cause of silent bugs which are hard to track.

Answer (score 2):

What it tells you is that you are sending an URL object while it expects an URI.

just change

```
dt.browse(uri.toURL()); // has error
```

to

```
dt.browse(uri); // has error
```

before being able to use Desktop, you have to consider if it is supported

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        // now enable buttons for actions that are supported.
        enableSupportedActions();
}
```

and the enableSupportedActions

```
private void enableSupportedActions() {
    if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        txtBrowserURI.setEnabled(true);
        btnLaunchBrowser.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

that shows that you have to check also, if BROWSE action is also supported.

Answer (score 1):

use some thing like this

```
try {Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.google.com"));
} catch (Exception e) 
{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}
}
```